# Python Py2app packaging directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, packaging, python-import, py2app

am getting an error about calling a method from a group of python files bundled with py2app

(1) I have read various info on the py2app importing large directories or package groups etc. but it seems to have problems interacting with said files. I hard coded each file to be included via my setup, however it still says it can't call a function from my file 'random.py' which generates its own script to run through 'happy.py' <- it runs perfectly on its own and all the dependencies are correct (imports from etc.)

(2) to make this even more complex the app is run 100% via terminal so I'm not sure if I will just need to send people the .exe in order to use since I assume py2app will just run the script without any options for user input..

```
SETUP FILE     
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['happy.py']
DATA_FILES = ['happy.pyc',
 'random.py',
 'random.pyc',
 'happy.py',
 'screener.py',
 '__init__.py',
 'screener.pyc',
 'setup.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    py_modules=['random', 'screener', '__init__','happy',],
    setup_requires=['py2app'],


)



ERROR OUT(given by .exe inside of .app, since .app runs a console error 255 with 0 info) 

                                                      | | _____   _____| | / |
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>: | |/ _ \ \ / / _ \ | | |
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>: | |  __/\ V /  __/ | | |
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>: |_|\___| \_/ \___|_| |_|
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>: 
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:   File "/Users/random/Desktop/bla/dist/happy.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 373, in <module>
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:     _run()
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:   File "/Users/random/Desktop/bla/dist/happy.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 358, in _run
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:     exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:   File "/Users/random/Desktop/bla/dist/happy.app/Contents/Resources/happy.py", line 275, in <module>
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:     print testone()
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:   File "/Users/random/Desktop/bla/dist/happy.app/Contents/Resources/happy.py", line 52, in testone
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>:     from random import function
Sep  9 04:39:12 softroot.local happy[39888] <Notice>: ImportError: cannot import name function
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `random.py` a custom script written by you, or is it the module from Pyhton standard?

Have you tried to copy the `random.py` from the resulting application package, `import random`, check `random.__file__` to make sure it is this one, and the try to execute the line with problems `from random import function` ?

Comment: I re named it and then realized py2app is best for GUI apps and went with cx freeze which worked fine.

Comment: py2app works fine even with non-gui applications. But I am glad that cx-freeze works for you.

Comment: do you know how to bundle a solely terminal based program and let it build it with py2app with all the dependencies included from importing modules? the 255 error has the worst documentation and is the reason why I switched.

Comment: I would recommend you to include IDLE with your distribution, to obtain the "terminal" effect. It is a lightweight tool. To accomplish that, add 'idlelib' to the 'packages' option when you configure py2app. I can add a short code snippet if you think that will be useful.

Comment: yes if you could that would be helpful...
thank you! ill try it out and post back if i cant get it to work. I did not think to include idle thats a good idea